# How can I upload one file at a time using sendKeys() in protractor

Tags: upload, protractor, sendkeys

In my project, I have a webpage where I can drag & drop a file, when doing e2e testing by protractor, I have to upload it using sendKeys() with the absolute path of my file, here is test script:

```
    var path = require('path');
    var remote = require('selenium-webdriver/remote');
    it("===> it will upload document", function () {

      browser.setFileDetector(new remote.FileDetector());
      let exePath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../bbb/' + fileName);

      $('button[type="button"],[type="file"]').isDisplayed().then(function () {
          $('input[type="file"]').sendKeys(exePath);
      });
    });
```

it's working well when I upload 1st file, but when I tried to upload 2nd file using the same code but just update the filename, The 1st uploaded file is automatically uploaded again alone with the 2nd file, instead of only uploading the 2nd file, so I got double 1st file which is not expected. would like to find a way to upload one file at a time, please help, thanks.

Comment: do you loop to upload the second file.

Comment: no，I repeated the same code and only changed the file name. I also tried to renamed variable exePath to exePath2, but the issue remained

Comment: Can you `log` the `exepath` and `exepath1` as `console.log(exepath)` to confirm the path

Comment: Yes， I debugged and watched the values of exepath and exepath2 specifically, they're populated correctly. only one file included...